# Use of other's SMTP server to send emails to avoid on be half of or phishing warning

Tags: php, email, smtp, spam-prevention

I am creating a tool for project managers. For notifications, we have done automated email module. Whenever email gets sent to team members, it says

```
 FROM :  "Sushant Danekar" "<"notification@mytestserver.com">"
```

or in some software it Says

```
 on behalf of 'Sushant Danekar'.
```

I had added `sender's` email address in `Reply-To` field while I had added `"notification@mytestserver.com"` email address in `FROM` field.

To avoid above mentioned issue I changed `From` address to `Sender's email address`

But now, Gmail has marked my message as spam and it says **"this message may not have been sent by"**.

I need a suggession to avoid both of these issue 1) `On behalf of` 2) `this message may not have been`.

I am open for all suggestions

I also thought of accepting SMTP details [username, password and SMTP server details] from user and while sending an email.

Is it the right way?  Does it create problem for our tool in future ? What are the RFC standards ?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are doing or what the problem with that is. Show the actual email headers you are using. The "on behalf of" text is displayed by some clients when there is a `Sender:` header but if your description is anything close to correct, it might just be because you have grave syntax errors in the `From:` header.

Comment: I guessed that its not clear. Our client is expecting to do something similar to what Gmail does. We can use our 1-2 email address from different domain/company in Gmail which allows to send email FROM configured email addresses. So is it the right method to ask and store smtp details for each PM user and then sending emails will be directly from that particular SMTP server.

Comment: I'm afraid your comment does not clarify what your issue is. Maybe you should review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Should I ask each PM user in my software to PUT smtp details for his email address? And If that is provided Should I use that SMTP server for sending out emails for him?

Comment: @tripleee I have updated the question, hope this will help you to clear his doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The header line you are showing has a number of syntax errors.

- There can be no space between `From` and `:`
- You have excessive quoting, some of which prevents correct parsing of the address

The proper way to format this address would be

```
From: Sushant Danekar <notification@mytestserver.com>
```

(or you could keep the quotes around your name, but that would imply to a human reader that it isn't really your name<sup>1</sup>).

If fixing that does not correct the problem, maybe post a new question with full headers of a failed message, detailed diagnostics from a spam filter, and/or a screen shot which shows the problem in an email client (indicate which one; include several if you can).

---

<sup>1</sup> There were situations where traditionally a person's name had to be quoted, but only if it contained symbols which have a special meaning to [RFC5321](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5321), such as a single quote.

```
From: "Paddy O'Reilly" <padster@example.com>
```

These days, the solution to that is to use [RFC2047](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2047) encoding on human-readable fields where necessary.

```
From: =?utf-8?B?Paddy_O=27Reilly?= <padster@example.com>
```

Any modern client will transparently decode that for proper human display.